# How to get Mysql data in javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery-ui

I have 3 textfields (Product name, product code and company name) in a form.

In the first field after selecting product name from ui auto-complete list I need to automatically populate product code and company name from mysql database.

I've tried the code below but am only successful in getting product name through javascript onKeyUp event.

```
// java script code

if(obj[i].name == "product_name[]") { var product_name = obj[i].value; }
if(obj[i].name == "product_code[]") {
  if(product_name) { obj[i].value = product_name; }
       else { obj[i].value = 0; }
 }

// Html code
<input type="text" name="product_name[]" id="product_name" onKeyUp="getValues()">

<input type="text" name="product_code[]" id="product_code" onfocus="getValues()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="pName" id="pName />
<input type="submit" value="Go"/ >
<?php
    echo"<input type='text' name='pCode' id='pCode' value='".$pCode. "' />";
    echo"<input type='text' name='cName' id='cName' value='".$cName. "' />";
?>
</form>

//PHP
$cName='';
$pCode='';
if(isset($_POST['pName']))
{
    $pName=$_POST['pName'];
    //get product code and company name based on pName from Database
    $record=mysql_query("select pname,cname,pCode from table
    where pname='". $pName. "'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($reocrds);
    $cName=$row['cname'];
    $pcode=$row['pcode'];
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer but i need value without submit, i need it on javascript onKeyUp event

Comment: then you have to use Ajax/JQuery

Comment: **Naveen Kumar** can you give me little hint for doing this with ajax

Answer (score 0):

get that sql data through any script language like PHP now set that data in PHP array and you can direct use that array in the javascript file because PHP easy embed in the javascript code

Thanks

Comment: **saiyam** yes we can easily embed php in javascript but look at the 3rd LOC in javascript code , i get product_name but tell me how to use it in sql query to get other related data